# what is physical meaning of this partial derivative?

Tags: momentum

what is physical meaning of this partial derivative:
$$\frac {\partial p_x}{\partial x}$$
i know how do i solve it when the case is just derivative but partial derivative is a bit Hectic!.

Comment: This question is lacking some context. A partial derivative is nothing but a normal derivative with the other variables taken as constants. What the physical meaning is depends on the function $p_x$.

Comment: If $p_x$ is momentum then the derivative is the spatial gradient along the `x`-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p_x$ is taken to mean momentum in the $x$ direction, $\frac{\partial p_x}{\partial x}$ simply means that momentum in the $x$ direction changes as you move along $x$. So for an object with a given mass, $\frac{\partial p_x}{\partial x}$ describes how its $x$ velocity changes as the object moves along $x$. In everyday life, that would just be called an acceleration or deceleration, such as braking a car that is moving east, if you call east $x$.

Where partials get more complicated is that you can have several such things going on at once. More specifically, you can have other independent accelerations or decelerations going on in $y$ and $z$ (think roller coasters). Finally, for a partial derivative that is expressed in terms of momentum instead of velocity, you cannot *always* assume the mass is constant, so you also cannot *always* assume that the effects are equivalent to velocity expressions.

Answer (score 3):

A partial derivative basically tells you how a function changes if I change just one of many variables it may depend on, while keeping all other variables constant.

On the other hand, a total derivative tells you the "TOTAL" information about the function. It describes how a function changes if all (or some) variables are changed together.

When a function depends only on one variable then ALL = one variable. In this case, a partial derivative is the same as the total derivative.

Answer (score 1):

The partial derivative of a function $f(x_1,x_1,x_3,..)$ at a point $(k,x_2,x_3,...)$, e.g. with respect to $x_1$, is the slope of the tangent line to the curve obtained by the intersection of the plane $x_1=k$, with the plot of $f(x_1,x_2,...)$.

The partial derivative also gives the rate of change with respect to the quantity being changed. Your partial derivative would give the rate of change of the momentum in the $x$ direction with respect to change in $x$, it essentially is a measure of how the velocity along the $x$ axis, if mass is constant changes, as you move along $x$, i.e. the change in a quantity along the direction you are moving in.